# Identification of shiny metallic blocks on the PCB

Tags: pcb, identification

**What are these shiny metal-like components in the images below?**

Is that kapton tape covering for ESD protection?

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like chip inductors? Bit hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: The pictures could be bigger.

Comment: I have added few more pictures of the same. You may check now.

Comment: Do they all have 3 terminals?

Comment: @jens I am new to this, but it seems like it. They all have similar markings, but the top color is different. I don't know why.

Comment: Can you provide more details of the board these components are on?  A broader picture would help, as would a very closeup photo

Comment: SMD film capacitors, definitely. Pretty rare, but very distinctive.

Comment: I don't know what the color means, if anything; it could be an accident of the process (natural film color, or optical interference, or dye added). It doesn't seem to be polyimide which is yellow/orange. You would have to contact a manufacturer of such known-colorful parts to get a direct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Hard to tell from the photo, but to me they look like SMD metalized film capacitors.

Lots of different film plastics can be used, including:

Polyphenylene Sulfide ([PPS](https://industrial.panasonic.com/ww/products/pt/film-cap-electroequip/models/ECHU1C472GX5))

[image]

Polyethylene Terephthalate [(PET)](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/40/cb_petht-3162319.pdf)

[image]

and Polyethylene Naphthalate ([PEN](https://industrial.panasonic.com/ww/products/pt/film-cap-electroequip/models/ECWU2682KC9)).

[image]

They are generally stable and low-loss, and often used in timing or converters circuits.

As shown by the PPS photo above, the electrode plates are sometimes visible, and I think this matches what is shown in the questioner's photo.

Some versions have a Kapton (or similar) film on top to provide some physical protection to the very thin capacitor plates.
 
Edit:

(When extra photos were added, it initially looked like the devices had 3 terminals, but careful inspection suggests the "middle" terminal is just silkscreen marking.)

(Images from respective linked datasheets.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to this, so I have few more questions.
What is that covering then? What is its purpose?

Comment: Probably these are silkscreen markings and not 3rd terminal. Also they look like metallized acrylic type, for example ECPU series from panasonic

Comment: For reference, here's a screenshot of how the footprints may have been drawn: i.stack.imgur.com/muRdY.png

Answer (score 3):

Could also be high reliability capacitors, which are constructed from two series connected stacks of plates, so that cracking and short circuiting which happens quite often, does not stop the capacitor from functioning. Often used in safety, automotive and other applications.